# Join two different columns from two different tables and merge duplicates

Tags: sql-server, join, union

i have two temporary table 
Table 1

```
 ID1         Name        ID2           Single
----------------------------------------------------
 1            ABC         1            100
 2            DEF         1            200
```

Table 2

```
 ID1         Name        ID2           Monthly
----------------------------------------------------
 3            PQR         2            500
 4            LMN         2            600
 1            ABC         2            700
 2            DEF         2            800
```

I want Output

```
 ID1         Name        ID2            Single   Monthly
--------------------------------------------------------
 1            ABC         1            100        700
 2            DEF         1            200        800
 3            PQR         2            NULL       500
 4            LMN         2            NULL       600
```

I used **all Joins , Union ALL , Union**  nothing working 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are using Sql Server 2008(other wise the insert statement in my query won't work). Try this one.
From the required out put, i guess you need all the values from table2 and there corresponding Single(Column name in table 1) value.

```
DECLARE @tempTable1 TABLE (ID1 INT,Name VARCHAR(10),ID2 INT,Single INT)
DECLARE @tempTable2 TABLE (ID1 INT,Name VARCHAR(10),ID2 INT,Monthly INT)

    INSERT INTO @tempTable1 VALUES
    (1            ,'ABC'         ,1            ,100),
    (2            ,'DEF'         ,1            ,200)

INSERT INTO @tempTable2 VALUES
(3            ,'PQR'         ,2            ,500  ),
(4            ,'LMN'         ,2            ,600  ),
(1            ,'ABC'         ,2            ,700  ),
(2            ,'DEF'         ,2            ,800 );
SELECT
                T2.ID1
                ,T2.Name
                ,T2.ID2
                ,T1.Single
                ,T2.Monthly

FROM            @tempTable2 T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN @tempTable1 T1
ON              T2.ID1 = T1.ID1
ORDER BY        T2.ID1
```

Comment: i need all the values from table2 and there corresponding Single(Column name in table 1) value and vice versa

Comment: In that case use full outer join instead of left outer join.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select coalesce(T1.ID1, T2.ID1) as ID1,
       coalesce(T1.Name, T2.Name) as ID1,
       coalesce(T1.ID2, T2.ID2) as ID2,
       T1.Single,
       T2.Monthly
from Table1 as T1
  full outer join Table2 as T2
    on T1.ID1 = T2.ID1
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/121659/

If you know that all rows always will be present in Table2 you can use a `right outer join` instead of `full join`.